# Hide Order which includes multiple Designer Products

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

We have e commerce shopping site with many products.

We have lot of **Designers** , each Designer is owner of multiple products.

We are displaying Designers in dropdown , once we select Designers  , than we can select Orders of those Designers , once we select Orders, than we can select related products.

Basically we are selecting all 3 dropdown fields and submitting form and saving values in database.

**1**. If order contains **products of only one designer**  , after we select those products and submit form, than again if we select same Designer ,  **previously selected Order will not visible**. Thats fine.
Ex: here you can see we selected "kidsdial2" as Designer and order "100000142" and submit form

[image]

so when we select "kidsdial2" **next time,** we can't see order "100000142"

[image]

**2**. If order contains **products of only multiple designers**  , after we select those products and submit form, than again if we select same Designer  **previously selected Order is Still visible**. But we want to hide "Order" here also. this is the issue.

Ex : here order "100000141" contains products of multiple designers. so we selected Designer "kidsdial2" & order "100000141" and selected products and submit form.

[image]

when we select "kidsdial2" **next time,** we don't want to see order "100000142".

[image]

**html**

```
<form  action="update_paidstatus.php" id="" onsubmit="return validate(); ">
    <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name="designer_id" id="designer_id">
        <option value="">Select Designer</option>
        <?php
        while($data = $stmt->fetch())
        {
        if($data['type']=="admin")continue;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['userID'];?>">
            <?php
            echo $data['name'];
            ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <div id="ordernumbers">
        <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id" class="designerorder_id" onchange='getProductDetail(this.value)'>
            <option value="">Select Order</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_id" id="dproduct_id">
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option>Select Products</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**script**

```
function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;    
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              //document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;
              $(".designerorder_id").html(result);

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }
```

**php**

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));

$htmltext='<select>';  
$htmltext.="<option value=''>Select Order</option>";

foreach ($order as $orderData) 
{

    $data=array();
    $sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";

    $sqlq=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlq1);

    while($rdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq))

    {
        $data[]=$rdata['dproduct_id'];
    }

    $orderitems=$orderData->getData('dproduct_id');
    $oitem=explode(',',$orderitems);
    $finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
    $result=array_diff($oitem,$data);
    $result1=implode(',',$result);

    if(count($result)>1)

    {  
         $result2=array(); 
         foreach($result as $product) 
           { 
             $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product); 
             $_productDesignerId = $_product->getDesignerId(); 

                if(trim($_productDesignerId) == trim($id)) 
                     { 
                         $result2[] = trim($product); 
                     } 
           } 

         $result2=implode(',',$result2);

        $htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$result2.'" name="'.$result2.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>';
    } 

}

    $htmltext=$htmltext."</select>";
    echo $htmltext;exit;
```

sample database :

[image]

**Edit - update_paidstatus.php**

```
$newURL="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/paidstatus.php";

if(isset($_POST) && $_POST!="" && !empty($_POST)){ // checking if form submision is occured or not.

    $sucessFlag=true;
    $productIds=explode(",",$_POST['dproduct_id']);

    $oDate = new DateTime($_POST['dueDate']);
    $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");   
    if(isset($conVar) && !empty($conVar) && $conVar!="")
    {
       for ($i=0; $i< count($productIds); $i++) {   

         $sqlQueryToUpdate="INSERT INTO order_details ( designer_id,designerorder_id,dproduct_id,dpaid_status,delivery_status,due_date) VALUES('".$_POST['designer_id']."','".$_POST['designerorder_id']."','".$productIds[$i]."','".$_POST['PaidStatus']."','".$_POST['PaidStatus']."','".$sDate."')";

            $sucessFlag=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlQueryToUpdate);
                if($sucessFlag==TRUE)
                    {
                       echo "UPDATE SUCESSFULLY";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo " not done.";
                    }           
         }
        header('Location: '.$newURL);  
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, i need to `hide order in dropdown if that order's products are already selected and submitted in form before`....

Comment: and its working only if order have `single designer'products`, but its not working if order have `multiple designer's products`.....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 why dont you go for ajax dropdown ?

Comment: @PranavMS thats much better , i have no idea about ajax , so  i ignored that one ,can you please help to get solution in some way......

Comment: Were do you "save" the selected orders?

Comment: @Glufu i am saving in `order_details` table , i posted sample database image in question, please check that.....

Comment: lets use the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132493/hide-order-which-includes-multiple-designer-products

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 In the php section '`$order` how are you getting its value ?

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 also the query in your update_paidstatus.php is a classic case SQL injection, please address that as well.

Comment: @gvmani please check updated question, we are using this code to fetch order details : `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider there are two designers D1 and D2.
Products P11 and P12 belongs to D1 and products P21 and P22 belongs to D2
Now there is an order O1 which has products P11 and P22
Check the inline comments.

```
    // fetches all order for the particular designer. Try to use = condition rather than like if possible.
// So as per our eg; If Desginer = D1 then  it will return O1
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$id.'%')); 

        $htmltext='<select>';  
        $htmltext.="<option value=''>Select Order</option>";

        foreach ($order as $orderData) 
        {

            $data=array();
// Will fetch the product id based on the designer id and desginer order id
// So in our eg: It will return only P1 since P2 is linked to D2
            $sqlq1="select dproduct_id from order_details where designer_id='".$id."' and designerorder_id='".$orderData->getIncrementId()."'";

            $sqlq=mysqli_query($conVar,$sqlq1);

            while($rdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq))

            {
                $data[]=$rdata['dproduct_id']; //P1
            }

            $orderitems=$orderData->getData('dproduct_id');
            $oitem=explode(',',$orderitems); // [P1,P2]
            $finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
            $result=array_diff($oitem,$data); //P2
            $result1=implode(',',$result);

            if(count($result)>1)

            {  
                 $result2=array(); 
                 foreach($result as $product) 
                   { 
                     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product); 
                     $_productDesignerId = $_product->getDesignerId(); 

                        if(trim($_productDesignerId) == trim($id)) 
                             { 
                                 $result2[] = trim($product); 
                             } 
                   } 

                 $result2=implode(',',$result2);

                $htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$result2.'" name="'.$result2.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>'; //order data gets appended
            } 

        }

            $htmltext=$htmltext."</select>";
            echo $htmltext;exit;  //order id with P2
```

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 what changes did you make ? I didnt make any changes to your code, was just explaining the reason.

Comment: From now, when someone say `engineer`, i will remember 2 names - one is `visweswarayya` & another one is you.....